# FInd bounding box of generated subtitles within ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to find the bounding boxes of subtitles I am burning in a video using ffmpeg, on frames I am extracting.

The naive way would be to split the output and save frames with/without subtitles, then do a difference using opencv and found surrounding area.

The more advanced way would be to do the comparaison within ffmpeg and save the comparaison. Currently I don't know enough of ffmpeg to do that.

The best way would be to be able to catch the bounding box values directly inside ffmpeg.

So I am asking for the best way to do it. If that's not possible, the more advanced way.

Subtitles are burnt with:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub.srt,fps=4 extracted/%05d.png
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose for doing this? I assume you are using the drawtext filter. Show your command.

Comment: I am generating datasets for benchmarking purposes. I need to get the bounding boxes of the subtitles on the frames. I use the `subtitles` filter (edited in the question)

Comment: I have found how to compute the difference of frames how to display the bounding box in the log: I use the `blend=all_mode=difference` for the substraction, then the `bbox` filter output to the log the coordinate of the bbox containing. I would like to redirect the output of the bbox filter only. Is that possible within ffmpeg or do I have to dosome scripting on top?

Comment: See the [metadata](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) filter. The keys are `lavfi.bbox.x1`, `lavfi.bbox.x2`, `lavfi.bbox.y1`, `lavfi.bbox.y2`, `lavfi.bbox.w` and `lavfi.bbox.h`

Comment: Okay that seems nice, where have you find the keys?

Comment: The keys need to be looked up in the source code, but I provided a first table here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide

Comment: Awesome, thank you.